# Having this issue with Syncfusion excel xamarin C# to edit or open an existing xlsx file

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

```
using System; 
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms; 
using Syncfusion.XlsIO; 
using System.Reflection; 
using Syncfusion.XlsIO.Parser; 
using Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation;

namespace Final {
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage { 
public MainPage() { 
InitializeComponent();  

}
    void click(object sender, EventArgs argd)
    {
        using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
        {
            IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
            application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2016;
            string filepath = "CustomerData.xlsx";
            Assembly assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream fileStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filepath);
            IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(fileStream,ExcelOpenType.Automatic);
            IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            worksheet.Range["A1"].Text = "Cake Name";
            worksheet.Range["B1"].Text = "Shape";
            worksheet.Range["C1"].Text = "Flavour";
            worksheet.Range["D1"].Text = "Weight";
            worksheet.Range["E1"].Text = "Message";
            worksheet.Range["F1"].Text = "MRP";
            worksheet.Range["G1"].Text = "Advance";
            worksheet.Range["H1"].Text = "Remaining";
            worksheet.Range["I1"].Text = "Date of Delivery";
            worksheet.Range["J1"].Text = "Order by";
            worksheet.Range["K1"].Text = "Mobile";
            int loop = 1, end = 0;

            while (loop == 1)
            {
                int index = worksheet.UsedRange.Column;
                worksheet.Range[$"A{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = cakeName.Text;
                worksheet.Range[$"B{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = shape.Text;
                worksheet.Range[$"C{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = flavour.Text;
                worksheet.Range[$"D{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = weight.Text;
                worksheet.Range[$"E{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = message.Text;
                worksheet.Range[$"F{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = mrp.Text;
                worksheet.Range[$"G{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = advance.Text;
                worksheet.Range[$"H{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(mrp.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(advance.Text));
                worksheet.Range[$"I{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = dod.Text;
                worksheet.Range[$"J{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = name.Text;
                worksheet.Range[$"K{Convert.ToString(index)}"].Text = mo.Text;
                if (end == 1)
                {
                    loop = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    loop = 0;
                }

            }
            FileStream file = new FileStream("CustomerData", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            workbook.SaveAs(file);
        }
    }
    void extclick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

    }
    void txt(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (advance.Text != null || mrp.Text != null)
            {
                remaining.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(mrp.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(advance.Text));
            }
            else
            {
                remaining.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(0)).ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
}
```

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream
at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.Collections.WorkbooksCollection.Open (System.IO.Stream stream, Syncfusion.XlsIO.ExcelOpenType openType) [0x00003] in <8dfe1c02e91946068d25619897754bee>:0
at Final.MainPage.click (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs argd) [0x00039] in <54e972018ba8404e93ba237b8c60e06d>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Button.Xamarin.Forms.Internals.IButtonElement.PropagateUpClicked () [0x0000a] in <e8dc484602bc4d36a6ebe969a1473467>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.ButtonElement.ElementClicked (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement visualElement, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.IButtonElement ButtonElementManager) [0x0001f] in <e8dc484602bc4d36a6ebe969a1473467>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Button.SendClicked () [0x00000] in <e8dc484602bc4d36a6ebe969a1473467>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonElementManager.OnClick (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Xamarin.Forms.IButtonController buttonController, Android.Views.View v) [0x00003] in <e986615d19ef46488aa957e2066baa1a>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FastRenderers.ButtonRenderer.Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener.OnClick (Android.Views.View v) [0x0000c] in <e986615d19ef46488aa957e2066baa1a>:0
at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_v) [0x0000f] in <e78694f8e35842ed9d7fc8bda8f9e790>:0
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V (_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0) [0x00005] in <e78694f8e35842ed9d7fc8bda8f9e790>:0

My code is here and this error comes I dont know how to handle this error So please help me

I am using Xamarin, Syncfusion.

I just want to open and edit an existing file of excel using syncfusion

I have searched every where what to do but could not found a thing .

Comment: Is this file included as part of your app bundle?  Or are you trying to create a new file at runtime?